# JSONArray parsing not working with https links

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am facing a strange problem. I am trying to convert the following STRING into String Array : [https://www.facebook.com,https://www.twitter.com,https://www.google.com]

using :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(vendorDetail.getSocialNetwork());
        String[] strArr = new String[jsonArray.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            strArr[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
        }


        if(strArr.length >= 1){
            fbLink= strArr[0];
        }

        if(strArr.length >= 2){
            twitterLink = strArr[1];
        }

        if(strArr.length >= 3){
            googleLink = strArr[2];
        }
```

and getting the following error: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 7 of [https://www.facebook.com,https://www.twitter.com,https://www.google.com]

NOTE: I am getting the string from the server-side response. Which should be converted into the String array

Comment: post string which is received from server.

Comment: caution. for him the two character points means value of the JSON key. you have to find the way to incorporate everything into a string.    ["https://www.facebook.com","https://www.twitter.com","https://www.google.com"]

Answer (score 0):

`str.split()`can change str to StringArray.Here is the demo

```
public void test(){

    String str = "[https://www.facebook.com,https://www.twitter.com,https://www.google.com]";
    str2Array(str);
}

private String[] str2Array(String str){

    if (str != null && str.length()>=2){
        str = str.substring(1,str.length()-1);
        String[] strArr = str.split(",");
        return strArr;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve result using `split()` method of the string class.

**Try it:**

```
String s = "[https://www.facebook.com,https://www.twitter.com,https://www.google.com]";
    s = s.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
    Log.e("My Replaced String", s);

    String[] split = s.split(",");
    for (String s1 : split) {
        Log.e("My Split String", s1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are getting the following error: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 7 of

because the array you have

`[https://www.facebook.com,https://www.twitter.com,https://www.google.com]`

which is incorrect,correct JSONArray is

```
["https://www.facebook.com","https://www.twitter.com","https://www.google.com"]
```

if you have the following array which is coming from json `["https://www.facebook.com","https://www.twitter.com","https://www.google.com"]` and you need it in String then you can do it as

```
try {
        String data= your JSONArray;
        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(data);
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    String facebook=jsonArray.getString(i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    String twitter=jsonArray.getString(i);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    String google=jsonArray.getString(i);
                    break;
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

for validate any JSON you can this website http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

If your response is

Case 1

> "[https://www.facebook.com,https://www.twitter.com,https://www.google.com]"

then try the simple one line code to convert it to string array

```
var str = "[https://www.facebook.com,https://www.twitter.com,https://www.google.com]";
str.replace(/^\[/,"").replace(/]$/,"").split(",");
```

Output will be

["https://www.facebook.com", "https://www.twitter.com", "https://www.google.com"]

Case 2

if your response is

> '["https://www.facebook.com", "https://www.twitter.com",
> "https://www.google.com"]'

then your code will work absolutely.